# detecting site visitor's city (for a site like Oodle.com)

Tags: php, geolocation, geoip

I am making a website that would allow users to post classified listings, buy/sell products etc. you can think of it as a limited version of Craigslist or oodle.com or something.

I want to automatically filter listings/results by user's city. How do I detect user's city?

There is MaxMind API that I could use to get city from ip address. Anything else?

Hmm.. what's the best way of implementing this? My site is going to be available in only 4-5 cities. If a user from outside of these 4-5 cities visits my site, I'd like to show "all" listings (that is, listings from all over US). Each of these cities have suburbs so I'd like to consider users from nearby suburb cities as part of my target city. How to code this? Should I look at the map and decide which suburbs to consider as part of target city or is there a way to decide target city + radius in miles/kms to be considered part of my target city?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want something like the [GeoIP City](http://www.maxmind.com/app/city) service.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was thinking. Any idea what oodle.com uses? what about groupon.com? If you go to groupon.com, it takes you to your city-specific page.

Comment: I'm not sure what they use... but it's probably not free, if that's what you're getting at. ;)

Comment: :-) Ok. Let's say you've the API. But how do you think oodle.com/groupon.com implemented this using MaxMind Geo IP City api? I mean, let's say you've a city "Seattle". But now someone from Bellevue is visiting the site. So, how does oodle.com figure out Bellevue is a suburb of Seattle?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion maxmind is good tool for ip detection and mapping with location, Below you can read documentation and they have uploaded sample code too, so you can get help from that
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/web-services